# Error al obtener valores en PHP

Tags: php, html5

Mi problema consiste en que al obtener el valor del input que tengo en mi html me da error y creo saber por que, a pesar de que todo lo pongo dentro de un formulario para usar el metodo POST cuando habro las herramientas de desarrollo de chrome me muestra que todas mis etiquetas tr y su contenido de las etiquetas td estan por fuera del formulario por lo cual php no puede caputar de forma correcta el codigo, alguien me puede indicar a que se debe esto y de haber otra manera de obtener el valor sin usar un input o usando otras etiquetas ¿me podria indicar la solucion por favor?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Mensaje</th>
                    <th>Conf.</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                include 'consulta.php';

                for ($i = 0; $i < $lista; $i++) {

                    $eliminar = $i + 1;

                    echo '<form action="eliminar.php">';
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo '<td>';
                    echo '<input type="hidden" name="eliminar" value="'.$eliminar.'">';
                    echo $lista['id'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $lista['nombre'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $lista['email'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo $lista['mensaje'];
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                    echo '<a style="margin-right: 5px;" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Modificar</a>';
                    echo '<button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>';
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</form>";

                    $lista = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

if( isset($_POST['eliminar']) ){
    $id = $_POST['eliminar'];
    echo $id;
    $reg = "SELECT * FROM forma WHERE id = '".$id."''";

    if ($re = mysqli_fetch_array($reg)) {
        $eliminar = "DELETE * FROM forma WHERE id = '".$id."'";
        echo "\nElemento eliminado";
    } else {
        echo "\nElemento no eliminado";
    }
} else {
    echo "\nNo se encontro el elemento";
}
```

Comment: Un primer problema que veo en tu código es esto dentro de un bucle: `echo '<form action="eliminar.php">'` ... estás creando tantos formularios como elementos haya en el array que estés leyendo. Para empezar, declara la apertura del `form` antes de empezar el bucle y lo cierras a la salida del bucle con `<form>`, el que uses una tabla o no es indiferente a condición de que no se esté produciendo un HTML erróneo. Otra cosa es que el nombre y otros datos no quedan dentro de `input`. Un `form` tiene una serie de elementos para meter datos, y si no los usas no se enviarán esos datos...

Comment: ... Eso no quiere decir que no puedes usar otros elementos, como `<td>` o `<tr>`, pero no es lo habitual y no sé si serializan con el formulario (no lo he probado). Me parece que no son serializados, entonces en ese caso tendrás que hacerlo a mano, vía Javascript y enviar los datos por medio de Ajax. Lo de Ajax no es mala idea para estos casos, tiene muchas ventajas que no vienen al caso ahora, pero para enviar datos lo más simple es usar `input`, `select`, `checkbox` y cosas así. ¿Por qué los quieres evitar?

Comment: Otra cosa es que si quieres usar POST como método debes ponerlo en el formulario, ya que si no lo pones, asume el método por defecto que es `GET`, entonces debes declarar el formulario así: `echo '<form action="eliminar.php" method="POST">'` y, en PHP si quieres revisar lo que está llegando desde tu formulario puedes hacer `var_dump($_POST);`... Uno de los problemas de no poner el nombre y demás datos en un `input` es que un `td` no es editable, no podrás por ejemplo cambiar ese dato si fuera preciso.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por el comentario realmente me ayudo ya hice lo que me dijiste y funciono, ahora respondiendo a tu pregunta de ¿por que los quiero evitar? la respuesta es porque fue una tarea que me dejaron en la universidad y yo sabia como hacer esto con ajax justo por el problema que mencionas, el problema es que la profesora como no sabe casi nada de javascript y mucho menos de ajax lo que ella no conoce dice que esta mal y califica con 0 asi que esa era la razon pero aun asi gracias por tu respuesta :D

Comment: Me alegro de que haya funcionado. Dado que al parecer sólo necesitas el `id`, puedes dejarlo así. Aunque no le veo sentido a usar un formulario con elementos del tipo `<td>`, dado que un formulario existe generalmente para poder modificar los datos y con un `<td>` no puedes hacerlo. Aunque puedes poner un `input` dentro de un `<td>`, pero bueno, eso es sobrecargar la página innecesariamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano justo eso acababa de hacer, gracias :D